# jQuery DataTable Parameters Undefined in Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

The following JavaScript renders either a green checkmark button or a red X button in a jQuery datatable column:

```
{
    data: "HasPayment",
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        if (data) {
            return '<button class="hasPayment\ btn btn-link" id=n-"' + meta.row + '"><span class="fas fa-solid fa-check" style="color: green"></span></button>';
        }
        return '<button class="hasPayment\ btn btn-link" id=n-"' + meta.row + '"><span class="fas fa-solid fa-times" style="color: red"></span></button>';
    }
}
```

The following JavaScript is called when one of the buttons (green checkmark or red X) is clicked:

```
$('#HR_Payment_DataTable tbody').on('click', '.hasPayment', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0];
    var data = $('#HR_Payment_DataTable').DataTable().row(id).data();
    var url = `Payment/Set?applicationId=${data[14]}&year=${data[12]}&month=${data[13]}&hasPayment=${data[11]}`;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            dataTable.ajax.reload();
        },
        error: () => {
            console.error("500 Internal Server Error.");
        }
    });
});
```

When I click one of the buttons, I get a console error that the values in `url` are undefined.

I am following this example: http://live.datatables.net/qemodapi/975/edit

This is how a row looks like

```
{
    ActivityPhase: "Complete"
    ActivityPhaseDate: "/Date(219999600000)/"
    Address: "123 N Main"
    AppNumber: 54
    Client: "Bob Ben"
    EscrowAccountNumber: "123456"
    EscrowWithCity: true
    HasPayment: false
    Hrdbid: null
    Id: "a21d627e-97ab-477f-afc1-27c2637f7c05"
    Month: 6
    Notes: null
    Year: 2022
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since data is passed into the DataTable as an array of object, data in each row will be represented as an object and not an array. So you should access members of the row (data of each column) any of the object access methods instead of that of an array.

Change this line

```
var url = `Payment/Set?applicationId=${data[14]}&year=${data[12]}&month=${data[13]}&hasPayment=${data[11]}`;
```

To this

```
var url = `Payment/Set?applicationId=${data['AppNumber']}&year=${data['Year']}&month=${data['Month']}&hasPayment=${data['HasPayment']}`;
```